# Aligning hyper linked images

Tags: html, css

Here's an image of before the problem.
[Before the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNdWu.png)
As you can see the logo(which is a hyperlink) and the shopping cart(which wasn't a hyperlink) are aligned.

Here's an image after adding the hyperlink to the cart image.
[After adding the hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXeXk.png)

I only added a hyperlink to the image and it seemed to mess up the alignment.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class = "headerLinkImage">
  <h1>
    <a class = "itemLink" href="../index.html"><img  class = "logoImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeLogo.jpg" alt="Logo"></a>
  </h1>
  <a class = "itemLink" href="islandTimeCart.html"><img  class = "cartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/shopping-cart-icon.jpeg" alt="ShoppingCart"></a>
</div>
```

The only thing I changed was adding the "a href" to the shopping cart image.

Here is the CSS code that stayed the same:

```
/*The "headerLinkImage" class is used to put the hyperlinked logo and image of the cart on the same line */

.headerLinkImage{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/*The "logoImg" class is used to change the style of the island time logo which sits at the top. */
  
.logoImg{
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 48%;
}

/*The "cartImg" is used to change the style of the image of the cart that sits at the top right. */
  
.cartImg{
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;  
}
```

Can someone 1) explain why the hyperlink messed up the alignment and 2) how to align both hyperlink images to the way they were before?

Also as a bonus if someone could help me get rid of the white space above the logo and shopping cart that'd be great. But mainly just want to get the alignment fixed. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: wrap a tag means cartImg position is  relative to the position of a, because you use ` position: absolute;` before you added the a tag. cartImg  is  relative to `headerLinkImage` that's why alignment messed up

Answer (score 0):

I provider the demo code as below.
I add an extra to use the `space-between` to help align. for the cart.
`font-size:0px` to help remove extra space

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    h1 {

      font-size: 0;
    }



    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .itemLink {

      font-size: 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    /*The "headerLinkImage" class is used to put the hyperlinked logo and image of the cart on the same line */

    .headerLinkImage {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;

    }

    /*The "logoImg" class is used to change the style of the island time logo which sits at the top. */

    .logoImg {
      /* height: 20%;
      width: 20%; */

      /* margin-left: 48%; */
    }

    /*The "cartImg" is used to change the style of the image of the cart that sits at the top right. */

    .cartImg {
      /* width: 5%;
      height: 5%; */
      /* position: absolute;
      right: 5%; */
    }

    .cartLink {
      position: relative;
      right: 5%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="headerLinkImage">
    <div></div>
    <h1>
      <a class="itemLink" href="../index.html"><img class="logoImg" src="https://picsum.photos/40/60" alt="Logo" /></a>
    </h1>
    <a class="itemLink cartLink" href="../index.html.html">
      <img class="cartImg" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="ShoppingCart" />
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give width in pixels
2. Dont give height browser will auto compute the height according to aspect ratio
3. I will require you full html to understand why you have a top margin
4. explain why the hyperlink messed up the alignment
   Hyperlink is not Messing up the alignment but your position absolute is messing it up
5. how to align both hyperlink images to the way they were before?
   I have added the code in below codepen use this code to align hyperlink images
   I have added comments for every code of css i add

Please Dont forget to like the codepen

Refer To This Pen
https://codepen.io/thisiskamaljoshi/pen/BaGRzzz

```
    <div class = "headerLinkImage">
    <h1><a class = "itemLink" href=""><img  class = "logoImg" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/673/954/png-transparent-google-logo-google-s-google-text-trademark-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></h1>
  <a class = "itemLink" href=""><img  class = "cartImg" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20190531/ourmid/pngtree-shopping-cart-convenient-icon-image_1287807.jpg" alt="ShoppingCart"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much for the help! I tried liking your code pen but it was making me pay for a subscription. If there is a way to like without paying, comment back and I'll do it as a thanks :) Appreciate and have a good one.